# Autocompletion with Lucene

Tags: lucene, continuations

Is it possible to obtain continuations of a text depending on the content of the Lucene index?
Does Lucene provide the API for this?
For example, to query with a simple text consisting of a few words and to obtain possible continuations (a few words) based on the content of the index.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask] for advice on how to write a good Stack Overflow question.

Comment: As it is currently written, your question is very high-level and does not contain any information about any _specific_ programming problem you may be facing. You can improve your chances of getting a good answer by editing your question to provide (a) some data examples showing what you want to achieve; (b) any research you have already done; (c) any code attempt you have already made, together with notes on what happens when you run your code, and any errors generated.

Comment: One place to start is the [suggest](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_11_0/suggest/index.html) library. But there are other approaches also - it depends...